# Is the Acronis version coming with Intel SSDs working with other manufacturers SSDs?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone

I got myself a new Thinkpad with a HDD and an extra Samsung SSD. 
Now I want to clone my Thinkpad´s HDD to the Samsung SSD. Unfortunately, the Samsung Data Migration software won´t support cloning my recovery partition.

On my desktop PC, I have an Intel SSD installed, which comes with an Intel-Version of the Acronis data migration tool. It says that I need an Intel SSD installed on the system in order to use it, not that it will only work with Intel SSDs. So I could try to attach both drives to my desktop PC and clone it with the Intel-Acronis tool. Still, I am not sure if the Intel version of Acronis is the same as the regular one. Mainly I am afraid to maybe damage my Samsung SSD with a Software that is maybe not a regular Acronis, but one tailored especially to Intel SSD´s.

Q: Does anyone know if I can use Intel´s Acronis version safely on my Samsung SSD?

Comment: DO NOT CLONE IT!!!! because a traditional hard disk and ssd are completely different during the install the OS has to configure the OS differently for SSD

Comment: @AndrewCrawford - This is completely false.  I have restored a clonedimage of a SSD's before onto SSDs and HDDs.

Comment: The migration tool is OEM independent

Comment: I never said you can not clone it, @Ramhound are you not aware of the settings that have to eb configured by the os on install for ssd?

Comment: @AndrewCrawford - The software described in the question does everything that is required and is not OEM specific.  I am not aware of any configuration differences that are required, I have never had a problem, also never did anything special except disable hibernation and configure the page file to be placed on a mechanical drive.

Comment: There is certain settings which can only be configured on install for SSD to allow it to reduce read/writes that ain't required and also use certain other properties of the SSD and disable some others, yes cloning it will not do much harm but will shorten the life of the SSD and you will not achieve the maximum potential from SSD

Comment: The only setting that you may want to set when cloning from HHD to SSD is make sure you have AHCI turned on in BIOS so you get TRIM  support. Nearly all new PCs for the past 5 years come with this option already enabled. You cannot easily enable AHCI after you have installed the OS either, because it expects to not use ACHI. There are hacks available to make this work, but in that scenario your better off reinstalling. AFAIK, the only thing you gain from using AHCI is TRIM support, it doesn't affect the speed of the SSD at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just tried it - connected both drives to my Desktop PC and started the Intel/Acronis data migration tool.

The tool can be installed and started if an Intel SSD is found on the system, but wont clone to a drive that is not from Intel.

The only "consolation prize" is that you get a ~40% discount on the Acronis full Version if you buy it from the link provided within the Intel/Acronis tool.

Comment: You should mark this as answered.